# How to change the text of input with Jquery with 3.1.1.?

Tags: jquery

I want to change 2 text elements of input fields with jQuery 3.1.1. from Yes=> Up, No=>Down, but I got this not working with jQuery or Javascript. I honestly do need help.

```
<div id="mxui_widget_RadioButtonGroup_351" data-mendix-id="281_14" class="mx-name-radioButtons2 dd" focusindex="0" widgetid="mxui_widget_RadioButtonGroup_351" style="">
    <div>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="1556006129938-1719" value="true">Yes</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="1556006129938-1719" value="false">No</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried several attempts and looked around 30 posts and tried the following but failed:

```
$('input.radio-inline')[0].html( "Omhoog" );

 $( "input:last" ).text( "Omhoog" );
/* $( "label" ).next().html('<input type="radio"  value="true">Omlaag</label>') */


/* $( "input[value='true']" ).text( "Hot Fasasauzz" );


$( "input[value='Hot Fuzz']" ).next().text( "Hot Fasasauzz" ); */
```

This is what I expect at the end:

```
<div id="mxui_widget_RadioButtonGroup_351" data-mendix-id="281_14" class="mx-name-radioButtons2 dd" focusindex="0" widgetid="mxui_widget_RadioButtonGroup_351" style="">
    <div>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="1556006129938-1719" value="true">Up</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="1556006129938-1719" value="false">Down</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you modify the Html at all?  At the moment it's difficult because the text you want to change is the text property of a label, and the label also contains the radio input, so if you *did* change the text, you'd lose the label.  This can be handled, but would be much better if the Html could be modified to have a label *and* a separate radio input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not the text of input, but of `label` element. You could loop through each of the label with class `radio-inline` and update the `textContent`, like:

```
$('label[class="radio-inline"]').each(function() {
    var el = $(this).contents().last()[0],
    textContent = el.textContent;

    if(textContent === 'Yes') {
        el.textContent = 'Up';
    }
    else if(textContent === 'No') {
        el.textContent = 'Down';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jquery code as well:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('label.radio-inline').each(function(){      
    if(($(this).text().trim())=='Yes'){ 
    $(this).text('Up'); 
    }   
else if(($(this).text().trim())=='No'){ 
    $(this).text('Down');
    }        
  })
})
```

this will work well, but we need to make some slight modification in html structure as below

```
  <div id="mxui_widget_RadioButtonGroup_351" data-mendix-id="281_14" class="mx-name-radioButtons2 dd" focusindex="0" widgetid="mxui_widget_RadioButtonGroup_351" style="">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="1556006129938-1719" value="true" />
       <label class="radio-inline">Yes</label>
       <input type="radio" name="1556006129938-1719" value="false" />
       <label class="radio-inline">No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access the children elements including the text nodes using `childNodes`:

```
$('label.radio-inline')[0].childeNodes[1].nodeValue = 'Up'
```